# Typing defaulted passthrough props in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript3.0

It is common for React components to accept and pass through some of their props to their children. In the case where one or more props on the child are optional due to being specified by the child's `defaultProps`, how does one define a `type` or `interface` for the parent that accepts both its own and its child's props correctly?

Consider the following illustrative example:

```
interface ParagraphProps {
  body: string,
  imgSrc: string,
}

interface SectionProps extends ParagraphProps {
  title: string,
}

class Paragraph extends React.Component<ParagraphProps> {
  static defaultProps = {
    imgSrc: '../images/section-break.jpg',
  };

  render() {
    const { body, imgSrc } = this.props;

    return (
      <p>{body}</p>
      {!!imgSrc && <img src={imgSrc}>}
    );
  }
}

class Section extends React.Component<SectionProps> {
  render() {
    const { title, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <section>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <Paragraph {...rest}>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, declaring `<Section title='T' body='B'>` will result in the error:

> Property 'imgSrc' is missing in type [...]

If instead we define props for `Section` like so:

```
interface SectionProps {
  title: string,
}

type FullSectionProps = Partial<SectionProps & PartialProps>;
```

Then we find that now `title` and `body` are optional, which is not what we want.

While remaining DRY, how should I specify the props for `Section` to stipulate that `title` and `body` are required and `imgSrc` is optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ParagraphProps` interface corresponds to the `Paragraph` component, it would probably make sense to keep those "aligned". You know that `imgSrc` has a default value, so it makes sense to mark it as optional in the interface because *no-one* using the `Paragraph` component (not only the `Section` component) is required to pass in `imgSrc`.

```js
interface ParagraphProps {
  body: string,
  imgSrc?: string,
}
```

If it isn't the case that all users of the `Paragraph` component need to pass in `imgSrc` (other than the `Section` component) then it probably makes more sense to move that default value to the `Section` component for `imgSrc`.

Finally, if you wanted to make this more dynamic, you could do something like the following, although it's probably more complex than necessary in this example.

```js
// Only needed if not 3.5+ (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type)
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface ParagraphProps {
  body: string;
  imgSrc: string;
}

type PropsWithDefaults = keyof typeof Paragraph.defaultProps;
type TransformedProps = Partial<Pick<ParagraphProps, PropsWithDefaults>> &
  Omit<ParagraphProps, PropsWithDefaults>;

interface SectionProps extends TransformedProps {
  title: string;
}

class Section extends React.Component<SectionProps> {
  render() {
    const { title, ...rest } = this.props;

    return <Paragraph {...rest} />;
  }
}

class Paragraph extends React.Component<ParagraphProps> {
  static defaultProps = {
    imgSrc: "../images/section-break.jpg"
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

<Section body="foo" title="baz" />
<Section body="foo" title="baz" imgSrc="override" />
```

Here, the `TransformedProps` type comprises all props from `ParagraphProps` where those found in `Paragraph.defaultProps` are made optional through the use of `Partial`. See the [Advanced Types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) for further details on how `Pick` and `Omit` form this construction.